# How to change tooltip background in extjs3.4

Tags: tooltip, background-image, background-color, extjs3

I am adding a tooltip dynamically to a grid using `metadata(metadata.attr="ext:qtip='tooltip'")` 
in extjs 3.4.

but i want to add this tooltip to each and every cell in the grid and tried in the following way instead of using above method

```
 function setToolTip(val, metadata) {
        new Ext.ToolTip({
                target: 'company',
                html: 'Click the X to close me',
                title: 'My Tip Title',
                autoHide: false,
                closable: true,
                draggable:true
            });

        return val; 
    }
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                id       :'company',
                header   : 'Company', 
                width    : 160, 
                sortable : true, 
                renderer : setToolTip,
                dataIndex: 'company'
            }
        ],
        stripeRows: true,
        autoExpandColumn: 'company',
        renderTo: document.body,
        height: 350,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Array Grid',
        // config options for stateful behavior
        stateful: true,
        stateId: 'grid'
    });
```

for the target i am giving the id of the Ext.grid.Column which i used in the grid.
But i am not getting the tooltip even though i am this line in the starting of the page

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `bodyStyle`, you can find it here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.ToolTip-cfg-bodyStyle